# Laravel storage file

Tags: laravel, file-upload, upload

in my shared hosting (without SSH) my laravel installation save file from form only in storage/app/public/namefolder but not in storage/namefolder and this causes the files not to be displayed.

How can I solve it? Is there anything I need to change in the filesystem of the online site on shared hosting? or do I have to do anything else?

thanks a lot

this is where i store my file

```
        'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],
```

Comment: How are you storing your files? Also, provide the details of your `config/filesystems.php`. Please, update your question with this details. [ask]

Comment: Thank you, i have update my question!

Answer (score 0):

i think your problem that you can not make the symlink command for storage as you do not has a SSH

```
php artisan storage:link
```

this command will create a symlink - a shortcut- to storage directory inside public directory,

there is several ways to apply this command with out accessing server via SSH

```
Route::get('artisan-command', function(){
   Artisan::call('storage:link');
});
```

or you can call it with in a class

after you run the command every thing will work just fine , and no need to change config more than usual stuff.

Comment: since I can't use the artisan commands because I don't have ssh access do you advise me to insert this code in the web routes?

```
Route::get('artisan-command', function(){
   Artisan::call('storage:link');
});

```

Comment: this is the error: symlink(): No such file or directory

Comment: check id you have a folder named storage in public folder and remove it , this sometimes happened form ftp client software , it convert symlink to folder , which is not linked to original storage folder